# Is it possible to check if two pointers points to the same object?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's consider this code:

```
char arr[10];
char *ptr1 = &arr[0];
char *ptr2 = &arr[5];
```

or

```
int i;
char *ptr1 = &i;
char *ptr2 = ptr1 + 1;
```

Clearly, these two pointers points to the same object. But is there any way to determine this afterwards in code? Is it possible to write a function like this?

```
// Returns true if p1 and p2 points to the same object and false otherwise
bool same_object(void *p1, void *p2) {
    if(<condition>) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I suspect this is impossible since you cannot retrieve the size of an array just from a pointer, but I wanted to make sure if there's something I may have overlooked.

Comment: No, not really. All you know from a pointer is the address it holds as its value. Nothing more. Now if you know where an object begins and ends, you can deduce whether two pointer point into it, but that is the opposite of being able to get information from the pointers themselves. (in other words -- *"you ain't missin nothin..."*)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I assumed as much. Thanks.

Comment: For a `char*` the "*object*" it points to is a `char`, and those two do not point to the same char. Whether they point to chars that are part of the same array cannot be determined without additional information.

Comment: It is possible (more or less) combining `_Generic` and `sizeof` to get an offset provided that the first argument is always the beginning of the object

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass along the object address and size, or store them in file scope variables, then it isn't possible.

If you pass along the object and its size to a function, then it will be perfectly possible. Something similar to this is well-defined for a generic object (no matter if scalar, aggregate, union):

```
bool same_object (size_t         objsize, 
                  const uint8_t  obj [objsize], // pass any object cast to const uint8_t* here
                  const void*    p1, 
                  const void*    p2)
{
  uintptr_t start = (uintptr_t)obj;
  uintptr_t end   = start + objsize;
  uintptr_t i1    = (uintptr_t)p1;
  uintptr_t i2    = (uintptr_t)p2;

  return i1 >= start && 
         i1 < end    && 
         i2 >= start && 
         i2 < end;
}
```

This is under the assumption that exotic systems will not implement `uint8_t` and normal systems will implement `uint8_t` as a character type.